# ngx-translate not working after migrating to Nativescript6 with Angular8

Tags: angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, ngx-translate

I have this issue after I migrated the app to Nativescript6 (automatic migration). Now, the translation are not working, in the console at start up time I see this kind of error:

```
JS: ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

But I'm not sure where that issue came from.

I run the lang json file in this tool and the result was good: https://www.jslint.com/

My package.json is:

```
{
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.company.app",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    }
  },
  "description": "my app name",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "8.0.0-beta.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "8.0.0",
    "@danvick/ngx-translate-nativescript-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.9",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "base-64": "^0.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "messageformat": "^2.0.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "8.0.2",
    "nativescript-bitmap-factory": "^1.7.1",
    "nativescript-dialog": "^0.1.0",
    "nativescript-fontawesome": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-ios-uuid": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-localstorage": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ng2-fonticon": "^1.3.4",
    "nativescript-open-app": "^0.2.0",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.3",
    "nativescript-platform-css": "^1.6.6",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "9.0.2",
    "nativescript-social-share": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-telephony": "^1.0.4",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-toast": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "7.0.0",
    "nativescript-version-number": "^1.1.0",
    "ngx-translate-messageformat-compiler": "^4.5.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "~0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "6.0.1",
    "ts-md5": "^1.2.4",
    "utf8": "^3.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.0.0",
    "@nativescript/schematics": "~0.3.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "8.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.1.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "1.0.1",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "3.4.5"
  },
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "author": "my company"
}
```

My app.module.ts :

```
import { HttpClientModule } from "@angular/common/http";
import { NgModule, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from "@angular/core";
import { NativeScriptLoader } from "@danvick/ngx-translate-nativescript-loader";
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule  } from "@ngx-translate/core";
import { TNSCheckBoxModule } from "@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox/angular";
import { AngularFontAwesomeModule } from "angular-font-awesome";
import { NativeScriptModule } from "nativescript-angular/nativescript.module";
import { NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule } from "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer/angular";
import { AppRoutingModule } from "./app-routing.module";
import { AppComponent } from "./app.component";

export function createTranslateLoader() {
    return new NativeScriptLoader("./assets/i18n/", ".json");
}

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        NativeScriptModule,
        AngularFontAwesomeModule,
        NativeScriptUISideDrawerModule,
        TNSCheckBoxModule,
        TranslateModule.forRoot({
            loader: {
                provide: TranslateLoader,
                useFactory: createTranslateLoader
            }
        })
    ],
    exports: [
        TranslateModule,
        TNSCheckBoxModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [
        NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA
    ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And the json files are in ´/assets/i18n/en.json´ (outside app folder)

One weird thing, is that when I inspect with the debugger, in the file explorer from chrome console, the en.json file is empty, it's like it is not being copied from the file in assets.

This was perfectly working before the migration to nativescript 6.0

Comment: I'd start by ensuring the `createTranslateLoader()` method is returning what you expect it to return.

Comment: @AndrewHill  What should tha return? The json keys with values?

Comment: I would imagine so - store a reference to it and console.log() it out. See what you get.

Comment: @AndrewHill, it's printing just this:
´JS: {
JS:   "prefix": "./assets/i18n/",
JS:   "suffix": ".json"
JS: }´

Answer (score 0):

You must update CopyWebpackPlugin in your webpack.config.js to include the asset folder

```
// Copy assets to out dir. Add your own globs as needed.
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
  { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
  { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
  { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
  { from: { glob: "assets/**" } }
], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```